# How can I calculate number of dues between two time periods?

Tags: awk, gawk

Here I have written a script for calculating dues of payments between two dates (mm/yyyy).

Generally the installments are paid 
monthly (12 times)
Quarterly (4 times)
Half Yearly (2 times)
Yearly (one time)

I am trying to arrive the "from due date" to "to due date".
I could calculate the number of dues correctly but unable to 
arrive at "to due date"

For example:

If the from due date is 11/2012
payment is quarterly
then as on 2016/06 the latest due is 05/2016

the total dues payable are 15

I have to show the dues from to as 11/2012 to 05/2016

Here I am stuck to arrive the latest due i.e., 05/2016

Here is my code:

curm=`date +%m`;
    cury=`date +%Y`;

```
awk -v curmt="$curm" -v curyr="$cury" 'BEGIN{FS="#"}{

mode=$10+0
fupy=substr($12,4,4)
fupm=substr($12,1,2)+0
prem=$11
if(mode==12){frequency=1}
if(mode==6 ){frequency=2}
if(mode==3 ){frequency=4}
if(mode==1 ){frequency=12}

if(fupm>6){        # here we are calculating revival dues as at 06/2016
       months       = (6+12-fupm) * frequency
           years        = ( curyr- 1 ) - fupy
       instalments1 = (years * frequency)+1
           fupyto       = fupy+int(instalments1/frequency)

               if(months>12){
                instalments2=int(months/12)
                            fractionofmonths=(months-instalments2 * 12)/frequency
                }else{
                     fractionofmonths=months/frequency
                                     }
                                fupmto=fupm+instalments2
            }else{
                        months = (6-fupm) * frequency
                    if(months <12){
                            years           = curyr - fupy
                            instalments1    = (years * frequency) + 1
                                        instalments2    = 0
                            fractionofmonths= months/frequency
                    }else{  
                                                years            = curyr - fupy
                        instalments1     = (years * frequency)+1
                        instalments2     = int(months/12)
                                    fractionofmonths = (months-instalments2 * 12)/frequency
                    }
                                fupmto=fupm+instalments2
                                     }
totaldues=0
totaldues=instalments1+instalments2
instalments2=0
instalments1=0


fupto  = fupmto"/"fupyto

..
..
..
some more code
}'
```

.
.
.
..
and some more code

Thank you

Comment: [edit] your question to clean up the code to make it more readable.

Comment: Are you clear about the right algorithm? The language used is not important here.